# How to compute geodesic area in GeoDjango?

Tags: python, geodjango, area, geodesic

I have some polygons which can be anywhere in the world. I would like to compute their areas.

The GeoDjango docs for `GEOSGeometry.area` don't specify whether it is geometric or geodesic area, but given that `GEOSGeometry.distance()` says that "GEOS does not perform a spherical calculation even if the SRID specifies a geographic coordinate system", I suspect that it is a simple geometric area.

I'm willing to write a little code, but the shorter the better, of course.

We do have a working geodesic distance function already.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340223.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to simply transform to an equal-area projection and compute the geometric area.

Comment: Accepting because this is what we ended up doing and it was accurate enough for our purposes; I believe it was much less than 1% off for the area of Colorado.

Answer (score 3):

if you use [PostGIS Geography Type](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography) for your table, you can calculate your area as you calculate on the plane surface.

> The geography type provides native support for spatial features
>   represented on "geographic" coordinates (sometimes called "geodetic"
>   coordinates, or "lat/lon", or "lon/lat"). Geographic coordinates are
>   spherical coordinates expressed in angular units (degrees).

creating geography(not geometry) table:

```
CREATE TABLE mypoly ( 
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(64),
    the_geom GEOGRAPHY(POINT,4326)
  );
```

hereafter is that using [psycopg2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2) for reaching postgis table and querying some sql with [ST_Area](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Area.html).

> ST_Area — Returns the area of the surface if it is a polygon or
>   multi-polygon. For "geometry" type area is in SRID units. For
>   "geography" area is in square meters.

in your view.py, write this code:

```
import psycopg2

def getGeodesicArea:

    res = []
    con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='mydb' user='reid' host='127.0.0.1' password='reid'")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT ST_Area(the_geom) FROM mypoly")
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        respre = row[2] # find your result.
        res.append(respre)     

    con.commit()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```

if you are searching a pythonic way for fetching your result as json, check out this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3287775/430408).

**UPDATE**

---

There is a javascript code in openlayers api for calculating geodetic areas. i think you can convert it to python for django application.

```
getGeodesicArea: function(projection) {
    var ring = this; // so we can work with a clone if needed
    if(projection) {
        var gg = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        if(!gg.equals(projection)) {
            ring = this.clone().transform(projection, gg);
        }
    }
    var area = 0.0;
    var len = ring.components && ring.components.length;
    if(len > 2) {
        var p1, p2;
        for(var i=0; i<len-1; i++) {
            p1 = ring.components[i];
            p2 = ring.components[i+1];
            area += OpenLayers.Util.rad(p2.x - p1.x) *
                    (2 + Math.sin(OpenLayers.Util.rad(p1.y)) +
                    Math.sin(OpenLayers.Util.rad(p2.y)));
        }
        area = area * 6378137.0 * 6378137.0 / 2.0;
    }
    return area;
}
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Sadly, there's no PostGIS in the system. The polygons are computed in Python and we need the areas without a database roundtrip.

Comment: check out my answer, i have updated it with a javascript code.

Comment: Can you summarize the algorithm that JavaScript code is using? For example is it doing the standard area-of-a-polygon computation with (non-ellipsoidal) geodetic distances between the points? Concise explanations of the principles are a lot more helpful to me than lengthy code to wade through....

Comment: it calculates the approximate area of the polygon were it projected onto the earth. it is referenced [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Polygon-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.getGeodesicArea) and more information about Some Algorithms for Polygons on a Sphere [here](http://trs-new.jpl.nasa.gov/dspace/bitstream/2014/40409/1/07-03.pdf)...

Answer (score 3):

The problem of computing the area of a polygon on an ellipsoid of
revolution where the polygon edges are geodesics is solved in Section 6
of

C. F. F. Karney,
  Algorithms for geodesics,
  J. Geodesy (2012);
  DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z;
  Addenda: http://geographiclib.sf.net/geod-addenda.html

Code (C++, Python, Javascript, and Matlab) that implements this solution
is available as part of GeographicLib, see

http://geographiclib.sf.net

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat higher-level view of Aragon's answer is as follows. In this paper:

> Robert Chamberlain & William Duquette, “Some algorithms for polygons on a sphere”. Proc. Association of American Geographers, 2007. ([PDF](http://trs-new.jpl.nasa.gov/dspace/bitstream/2014/40409/1/07-03.pdf))

there is a formula for computing area of a polygon on a sphere. Here's two different versions copied from the paper; one or the other might be easier to implement in a particular case.

[image: eqn1]

[image: eqn2]

$\lambda$ is latitude and $\phi$ is longitude. $R$ is Earth radius, and $A$ is the area you're trying to find.

I assume a sufficiently talented mathematician could extend this to a standard geographic ellipsoid, but spherical is good enough for me.